# update weblogic application name

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

#### Goal:

In picture I want to change app name only "app" **strong text**

[image]

#### Question:

Can I change or update deployed `weblogic` application name without stop managed server?

Additional information after a while. If you want to change application name in weblogic wlst console, it takes error message.

[image]

This shows us weblogic **ApplicationName property is a read only property.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot change the name even if you stop managed server. You have to redeploy the application specifying the name you want or manipulate config.xml and restart all server(Not recommended as it can cause issues if not done correctly).